# How to use aggregate functions in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I'm practising subqueries and I decided to use `max()` to get the max salary rate instead ended up with a error and this is not the first time I had this error but I never solved it. So do I need to use `group by` clause every time I use aggregate()? Please explain it to me layman words.

**Error I got :**

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
> Column 'HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory.BusinessEntityID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

**My query :**

```
select * 
from HumanResources.Employee
where BusinessEntityID = 
  (
     select eph.BusinessEntityID, max(rate) 
     from HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory as eph
  );
```

Comment: When you aggregate with an aggregate function like `max()` you must put the unaggregated columns in your `GROUP BY` clause. Add, as a last line to your subquery `GROUP BY eph.BusinessEntityId` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Why do you have `max(rate)` in your subquery? But yes, when you have aggregate functions in a query, every column must either have an aggregate function, or you have to group by it.

Comment: What do you really want to solve? Group By, yes, will fix the query, but that query is strange and likely not going to return what you want it to return.

Comment: After you make that change, your query will still need some work. I suspect that instead of `WHERE` clause, you likely want this subquery in your FROM clause as a derived table.

Comment: `where BusinessEntityID = ` also expects a single scalar value, so this is not the correct approach and your error, you would need `in()` and a query that returns a list of qualifying Id values.

Comment: The select list in that subquery returns **two columns**, but for this purpose you're only allowed to have one.

Comment: `where rate = (select max(rate) ...` is what you want. Getting the id of the row with max rate has always been a tricky SQL question. Check out `first_value()`

Comment: Honestly you need to take the time to take some tutorials and teach yourself the fundamentals of SQL AND spend the time to consider how your data looks and what you are trying to accomplish. Sure you'll get an answer to your question here, but that in itself won't help you next time you run into a similar but different problem.

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER` or `FIRST_VALUE` are almost certainly better solutions anyway.

Comment: @Andrew Because I want to use the maximum salary of a specific employee and get all other information about that employee from another table without using joins.

Comment: @Charlieface How ?? I mean, can you explain using some examples for them?

Comment: @DaleK Yeah, I know. I'm trying to clarify the confusion by practicing it. Reading and understanding is a bit difficult for me.

Comment: Typical example https://stackoverflow.com/a/6841644/14868997 You need to think about what your query says, and you'll quickly realize it makes no sense: how can a single `BusinessEntityID` equal two columns, or multiple rows?

Comment: @Stu Yep, I understood that, but if the inner query returns a single value, we use =, and when it returns a range of values, we use 'in' on the outer query. I'm using max(), which returns a single value. So shouldn't it be =?

Comment: You can run `select eph.BusinessEntityID, max(rate) 
     from HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory as eph GROUP BY businessEntityID` on its own and see that it will produce 2 columns and one record for each `BusinessEntityID` so it's clearly not a scalar result.

Comment: @Charlieface yep, I understand you are trying to say

Comment: I've updated my answer to use a correlated subquery in the select clause of the query. This eliminates the need for the explicit join, and because the subquery is correlated, it reduces the output to a single scalar value for each record in `Employee`. I *think* this is what you are trying to do now that I read through your comments.

Comment: @I'mveryconfused No - `in` works with 0 - N rows, your understanding is skewed because you've missed the need to `group by` so 1 *or more* rows could have the same max value - *always* think in sets.

Answer (score 3):

The GROUP BY issue is addressed in the comments, but your query still doesn't make sense and will likely still error as your `WHERE` clause isn't correct. Instead, I suspect you are looking to join the results of your subquery to your employee table to view the `max(rate)` of each `Employee`. This will look like

```
SELECT * 
FROM HumanResources.Employee emp 
  INNER JOIN 
    (
      SELECT BusinessEntityId, max(rate) as max_rate --an alias is needed in a subquery used in a join
      FROM HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory 
      GROUP BY BusinessEntityID --This missing part was throwing the error
    ) as eph
    ON emp.BusinessEntityID = eph.BusinessEntityID
```

Given your requirements of not using a join, one option where the join is not explicit would be a correlated subquery in your select clause. This is still joining the two tables, but using correlated subquery syntax.

```
SELECT emp.*, 
   (
      SELECT max(rate) 
      FROM HumanResources.EmployeePayHistory as eph
      WHERE emp.BusinessEntityId = eph.BusinessEntityId
   ) as max_salary
FROM HumanResources.Employee as emp
```

A few take-aways:

1. The `GROUP BY` can be removed since we are only returning the `max(rate)` in this subquery.
2. The return from this subquery is scalar since we correlated it for each `BusinessEntityId`
3. The where-clause has been added to maintain the relationship between the inner and outer query. This is the "Correlated" part of "Correlated Subquery".

Comment: Yeah, but I don't want to use joins and understand the workings of a subquery.

Comment: I've added a version of this query where the explicit join is moved to an implicit join using a correlated subquery.

Comment: Yep, Thanks for explaining !! I got it.

Answer (score 0):

As you wanted an explanation of Group by in layman's term.
Let's say you have a table with 3 columns: Name, Math and English

| Name | Math | English |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tina | 56 | 45 |
| Roy | 85 | 87 |
| Klarna | 45 | 36 |
| Resa | 23 | 95 |
| Tina | 89 | 96 |
| Resa | 41 | 78 |
| Resa | 68 | 51 |
| Roy | 96 | 63 |
| Tina | 75 | 52 |
| Tina | 36 | 34 |

Now you want to group the result by Name, hence, the names column will be grouped together like this:

| Name |
| --- |
| Tina |
| Roy |
| Resa |
| Klarna |

Then what about the other two columns? Math and English? How will SQL know what to do with those values? In your mind it will be like this:

| Name | Math | English |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tina | 56 | 45 |
|  | 89 | 96 |
|  | 75 | 52 |
|  | 36 | 34 |
| Roy | 85 | 87 |
|  | 96 | 63 |
| Resa | 23 | 95 |
|  | 41 | 78 |
|  | 68 | 51 |
| Klarna | 45 | 36 |

But how will SQL form a table structure out of the Group By instruction?
Hence, when you are grouping a column you need to instruct SQL what to do with other columns. Like SUM, Max, Min etc. Hence, aggregation is must when you are grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Just another option using `WITH TIES`

```
Select top 1 with ties *
 From  HumanResources.Employee
 Order By row_number() over (partition by BusinessEntityID order by rate desc)
```

---

**Note:**   If you want to see TIES ... change `row_number()` to `dense_rank()`